# Как коммиты перенести в свой аккаунт?

Tags: git, github

Постоянно выкладываю что-то на гит, с тех пор как учиться начал. Посмотрел на активность на главной страничке гита. Увидел что активность не везде. Начал копать и увидел, что по какой то причине, у меня слетела почта с гита. Стояла такая - git config user.email = test@test.ru. Изменил на нормальную.

Я посмотрел свои коммиты в свои ветки, и они шли не от меня от test3123123123 (что то типо такого). Я так понимаю, что активности на моей страничке и нет, потому что львая доля коммитов от этого test@test.

Каким образом можно быстро все под свою почту переделать?

Comment: Скорее всего существующие уже никак не переделать. Вряд ли Вам Github вообще это даст сделать. Новые уже можно, если напишете правильно свой логин и почту.

Comment: Вот этим скриптом можно изменить имя пользователя и email, только на большом количестве коммитов и на репозиториях с несколькими участниками лучше не делать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/4752653

Comment: А, вот дубликат нашелся

Comment: Помогло вот это вбитое в терминал (заменить имя на то которое хотите поменять) Запустится процесс, не мгновенный.  git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Newname'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='new@email'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='Newname'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='new@email';" HEAD

Comment: после этого заупскаем git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/main'

Comment: переписывание истории коммитов очень плохая практика